# Background Music in Android

Tags: android, audio

This is a very common but rarely solved topic.
I seriously need some help in this guys.

I got [this piece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928803/background-music-android) of code. Tried calling this service from the main launch activity. 
But no success, no sound.

kindly help coders. Thanks in advance!

Comment: And the link you have posted, seems to have a perfectly working code, with any issues resolved in the answer.

Comment: yea its working. but not for me. have tried number of formats.

Comment: Actually, the link posted in the OP's question has an accepted answer from somebody who says **"I think it should work, but I have never used MediaPlayer so I can't tell."** (read the comments on the answer). The code from the person who's answer was accepted is also 'broken' - even the code they posted to pastebin.

Comment: this is the main activity 
`public class SoundtestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
        startService(svc); 
        
    }
}`
and the link to the service is already available in the question

Comment: @KazekageGaara the link posted below works! and btw stackoverflow doesn't allow everybody to vote up. you got to have minimum number of points to do that. earlier and even today i don't have enough of them.
hence i can't.

Comment: @GursahibSahni no one is asking you to upvote. People are asking you to accept correct answers. Notice the tick right below the voting arrows(right next to the answers)? Click on that to accept answers. And have some sense instead of just showing your rage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- see this example by markana background service music.

  here is the [link](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html)