# Music in background

Tags: android

Who do I create an app that plays music in background of a call, audible to only the caller and the listener? Can any body suggest a method for doing it? I had tried to create a music service which is used for creating background service for apps, but it is not fully satisfying my goals.

I created a background music service according to this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App).

EDIT: IDEA---want to play a music in the background of a call which is audible to the caller and listener when the state is offhook

Comment: explain your question clearly

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your point clear, but it is not possible to play a audio file which the caller can hear, except maybe you use the speaks, at a high level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to play background music for your app , then play it in a thread launched from your app/use AsyncTask class to do it for you.

```
 public class BackgroundSound extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(YourActivity.this, R.raw.test_cbr); 
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping 
    player.setVolume(100,100); 
    player.start(); 

    return null;
}
```

}

Look https://stackoverflow.com/a/7928911/1697047 for more details