# adding background audio in android app

Tags: android

I was trying to add background sound for 5 sec. in the introductory screen of my app. I tried it on avd as well as on real phone but sound isn't working. where am i wrong?

I am copying java code of my main screen...

```
package com.example.akg;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Opening extends Activity {

MediaPlayer song;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_opening);

    Thread tim=new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                song=MediaPlayer.create(Opening.this, R.raw.music);
                sleep(5000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.getStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent inten=new Intent(Opening.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(inten);
            }
        }
    };
    tim.start();
}

protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    song.release();
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: you are missing `song.start()` tp play the song ...

Comment: See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928803/background-music-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To play background sound to your activity, use following code:

```
try {
            song=MediaPlayer.create(Opening.this, R.raw.music);
            song.prepare();
            song.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And to stop background sound, use:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(song != null && song.isPlaying()) {
        song.stop();
    }
}
```

This link might be helpful to you:
[Media Player with Play/Pause, Rewind, Forward, Previous and Next functionality with Seekbar](https://github.com/kalpeshmayani/MediaPlayer)

Comment: really its a great answer by you i appreciate your answer

Answer (score 0):

To play the sound, you need to call:

```
song.start();
```

From the android documentation for [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html):

> To start the playback, start() must be called. After start() returns successfully, the MediaPlayer object is in the Started state. isPlaying() can be called to test whether the MediaPlayer object is in the Started state.